# Opening ArcGIS Pro project (*.aprx) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, aprx

I have a project (APRX) in ArcGIS Pro and I want to open it in QGIS.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What makes you think you can?  I doubt this can be done.  An APRX isn't GIS _data_, it's a ArcGIS PRO project/document file

Answer (score 5):

Currently, there does not appear to be a way to do this. The APRX file extension was created by ESRI for its ArcGis Pro for its projects. It is an archive file that stores files of data in XML format to define and organize everything associated with the project. There is functionality built into ArcGis Pro to read, write, and parse this data in the manner it was designed. Because ArcGis is proprietary software we do not have access to the code used to read, write, and parse this data. That means, in order for us to be able to open an APRX file in QGis, someone would first have to reverse engineer the design of the APRX archive and then code a process for converting the XML data into a format usable by QGis. I believe it was done at some point for MXD files, so it's likely possible. However it would be an undertaking and no one, as far as I'm aware, has put the effort in to build it yet.